# Sound pressure level of speakers and hearing damage

Tags: speakers, spl, hearing-damage

I noticed that is common to buy home speakers that are advertised as 135 - 136 db. For example The box Pro.
But [here it says](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK390300/#:%7E:text=Sounds%20above%2090%20dB%20can,decibels%20(threshold%20of%20pain).) that sound pressure above 90 db can lead to hearing damage if you are exposed all the time, and above 130 db you feel pain.
So how can someone listen to a 135 db speaker then?

Comment: Stand at the back of the room.

Comment: What? Speak up. What?

Answer (score 1):

It's like a sports car that can go 300 mph, yet you'd never actually drive it that fast.

Specs to impress and sell the product, rather than be practical.

Also consider distance from the speaker — how close are you listening to it?

Another possible interpretation here is that if you wear hearing protection, people further away could hear the music. This is usually more suitable for commercial large-arena amplification that needs to carry across distances, rather than home speakers. In which case putting your ear right next to it would be deafening, but being yards away and affected by the sound output falloff, you can hear it at a more reasonable loudness.